# Drools 8.33 Decision Table Compilation Error

Tags: drools

I can not understand why drools (v8.33) fails to compile my decision table (see image). The failure is at Rule #6 and the output at runtime is:

```
Rule Compilation error : [Rule name='O6']
fill cannot be resolved
fill cannot be resolved
fill cannot be resolved
fill cannot be resolved
fill cannot be resolved
fill cannot be resolved
```

I suspect that the issue is that the fill object defined in the LHS "Exec Broker" Condition is not available in the RHS actions because there is only a Capacity condition needed for that rule.

Interesting that the error is printed 6 times (one for each rule).  However, if I remove Rule #6 the decision table compiles and runs just fine.

What do I put in the Exec Broker for Rule #6 or how do I extend the fill object across all actions and conditions?

[image: Drools 8.33 Decision Table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier with a reproducer (a small github repo demonstrating the issue).

That said, based on the screenshot, it seems to me in column E,F you are trying to reference a `fill` which is not matched in LHS.
For line16 in excel, column C is empty,

hence no match on `fill: Fill( execBroker == ...)`.

Did you wanted not to set the fill in column E,F? In that case, just leave cells E16 and F16 empty.
No RHS referencing `fill` would be produced.

Did you wanted to match *any possible* `Fill` object in memory? Even if that could mean multiple combination of `Leg` and `OrderMaster`, since there is no beta-join? In that case, it could help defining an alternative LHS column C, but without the `execBroker` constraint. Then valorize with an "X" (or any other content) in the related row line.

This is because, in this latter case, what you want to produce is the rules with the following:

```
rule 06
when
  leg: Leg( securityType == "OPT" )
  fill: Fill( ) // <-- notice you want without execbroker
  order: OrderMaster( capacity == "C" )
then
  ...
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi. Yes. The example .drl snippet for rule 06 you provided is exactly what I want.  My intention with row #16 is to set the Fee Detail and Fee Rate on the inserted fill object when the inserted OrderMaster object has a  Capacity = "C" regardless of what the the value of Exec Broker is on the fill - but I did not understand your suggestion on how to fix it regarding 'X'.  Would it be possible to explain in a little more detail perhaps with an example?

Comment: if you do not place a constraint on the line 9, in another column similar to currently-existing-coulumn-C I would expect it would generate an empty constraint but still a pattern if in the corresponding cell (say D16) you place an X. Not tested tho! But I do recall similar tricks to make it emit a pattern (`Fill()`) but with empty constraints.

Comment: Yes. This works but the solution is totally confusing to anyone who has to look at the spread sheet and try to understand what is going on.  Also, no such tricks were necessary in Drools 2.5 which I am, unfortunately, tasked with upgrading to 8.33.

Comment: It seems however your last comment would imply ("This works...") that you don't have beta-joins. In this case, you could consider expressing your logic with DMN, which Drools DMN support, which is more user-friendly for BA and SME.
You may continue by opening a thread on the drools-usage or kogito-development mailing list (google group).

Comment: kindly don't forget to accept this answer as valid, since you just confirmed it works ("This works"), thanks! @MichaelStarkie

Comment: OK.  I will accept this as the solution because it turns out that by adding another needed business condition to right of column D,  that actually uses a fill with a different constraint, solves the problem in the same way.  This is only a problem because I am porting a decision table from Drools 2.5 to Drools 8.33 and doing it incrementally.  I left out a bunch of conditions to the right of Column D